# Excel, counting positive numbers such that next column is top 10

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

I am looking to count/sum positive numbers in a column given that we are taking only top 10 in next column. For e.g.

[image: Sample data]

I am using the formula: =SUM(LARGE(IF($E$3:$E$58>0,$F$3:$F$58),ROW(A1:A10)))

But it is summing the top 10 right F column  such that E column is positive, which is the other way round. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the intended recourse if the 10th largest is a tie?

Comment: @pnuts I wanted to count and sum the column E such that it is positive and corresponding column F values are in top 10, as solved by Jeeped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound as if you need anything more elaborate than a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) and a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5). The [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) can provide a criteria to govern what is included in the count or sum. You've provided no row numbers so I will just use full column references.

[image: SUMIF/LARGE and COUNTIF/LARGE]

The formulas are in the image much as your sample data was. As you can see, I used a *greater than zero* to determine what is a positive number. These are *not* array formulas. I was a little confused why you were asking for a count as your description seemed to refer to the *Top 10*. Maybe you can transcribe this for your own purposes.